# how to get complementary information from sp_readerrorlog

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, security, audit, logins

when auditing what are the failing logins in one of my server, using the [sp_readerrorlog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/09b69020-cbab-4fe0-a5e2-2f4865dbdd85/spreaderrorlog) procedure I get the following result, when running the following query:

```
 EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Login failed'
```

[image]

it shows me the IP address of the servers where from the login was attempted.

I know that `ping -a` resolve ip addresses to hostnames

[image]

any ideas, even vague ones, or indications, as how I could get to those hostnames using T-SQL?

lets, say I can get to the ip address and put it into a variable. how then could I go and do a magic and get to the hostname for that particular ip address?

Comment: T-SQL isn't the right tool for the job, although you could use `xp_cmdshell` to invoke `NSLOOKUP` to resolve the host names. Consider executing the query in a PowerShell script, where you can get the host name  using the .NET `System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry()` method (e.g. `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other comments on your question indicated, there are probably better ways other than TSQL to get this data, but here is something I cobbled together using TSQL.

```
--Declare variables
--OldDelim and NewDelim are used to split on multi-char (Thanks to Aaron Bertrand for the idea)
DECLARE @olddelim NVARCHAR(10) = 'client:'
    ,@newdelim NCHAR(1) = NCHAR(9999);-- pencil (✏)
DECLARE @RowsToProcess INT
DECLARE @txt TABLE (txt VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @LogInfo TABLE (LogDate DATETIME,ProcessInfo VARCHAR(100),txt VARCHAR(max))

--Retrieve errorlog information
INSERT INTO @LogInfo
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0,1,'Login failed'

--temp table to hold the results of parsing the errorlog info
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataToProcess

--add row number to facilitate while loop processing and updates of temp table
SELECT *
    ,trim(replace(value, ']', '')) AS HostNameIP
    ,convert(VARCHAR(30), NULL) AS HostName
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY newid()
        ) AS rn
INTO #DataToProcess     --insert into temp table
FROM @LogInfo li
CROSS APPLY (           --cross apply split information to get HostIP
    SELECT value
    FROM string_split(replace(li.txt, @olddelim, @newdelim), @newdelim)
    WHERE value LIKE '%]%'
    ) ca

SET @RowsToProcess = (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM #DataToProcess
        )
DECLARE @cntr INT = 1

WHILE @cntr <= @RowsToProcess
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = 'nslookup ' + (
            SELECT HostNameIP
            FROM #DataToProcess
            WHERE rn = @cntr
            )

    DELETE FROM @txt
    INSERT INTO @txt
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd

    --Update temp table with HostName from nslookup
    UPDATE #DataToProcess
    SET HostName = (
            SELECT trim(replace(txt, 'Name:', ''))
            FROM @txt
            WHERE txt LIKE '%name%'
            )
    WHERE rn = @cntr

    SET @cntr += 1
END

SELECT LogDate, ProcessInfo, txt, HostNameIP, HostName
FROM #DataToProcess
```

---

```
| LogDate                 | ProcessInfo | txt                                                                                                             | HostNameIP    | HostName                |
|-------------------------|-------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|---------------|-------------------------|
| 2019-03-07 14:40:07.320 | Logon       | Login failed for user 'xyz'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.165.32.119] | 10.165.32.119 | sc-hgrckb2.anywhere.com |
| 2019-03-07 15:06:51.540 | Logon       | Login failed for user 'zzz'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.165.32.119] | 10.165.32.119 | sc-hgrckb2.anywhere.com |
```